# Javascript Same Origin Policy in Windows 8 Apps

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, windows-8, cross-domain

I'm trying to make a Javascript based app in Visual Studio that will access JSON data on a remote server. Will the Javascript Same Origin Policy prevent me from doing this or does that not apply in Windows 8? If the Same Origin Policy won't allow me to do this, what would be the best way to get around it?

Comment: This is a very broad question but the upshot is that OS does not matter when it comes to the SOP.

Comment: What Jay said, it has nothing to do with the OS. CORS must be enabled on your remote server in order to access the JSON client-side if you're trying to access it on a different domain.